# How do I log errors to a file, and distribute an email with the error with apache?

Tags: apache

How can I set up apache to email out errors as they occur in the log file?  I have tried [this example](http://insidenothing.com/?p=131), but after apache restarts, it does not seem to handle errors any more.

My goal is to have my team notified when there are errors on the server, so that we can address them in a timely fashion.

Comment: where is the failure ? can you send any other email with this PHP ? does the apache error log updates ?

Comment: @alfasin, the PHP in the example will send email when the service starts/restarts, but after that it will not send emails.  In addition, after that the logging seems to bypass the script. I think the stdin file handler is getting close, and as a result it is not handling any of the errors any more.

Comment: I didn't test it, but maybe it will help to `tail -f` the error log and pipe the output into the php-script